# Equilateral triangle - corona

Tags: lua, anchor, coronasdk

I made a equilateral triangle:

```
local W =   540 
local H = 700
local r =  150
local r_x = math.sqrt(math.pow(r,2)-math.pow((r/2),2))
local vertices = { 0,-r, r_x , r/2 , -r_x , r/2  }
local block = display.newPolygon( W, H, vertices )
physics.addBody( block )
physics.setGravity(0,0)
block.angularVelocity= 100
```

I want the triangle to rotate on its axis but it does not happen. why?
I thinks it related to the object's anchor but I dont know how to fix this.

Try yourself if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: and which axis would that be? the Y-axis; or the other two?

Comment: exactly at the middle. like it will rotate from the center

Answer (score 0):

Just take all the objects and insert them into a group.  Then just rotate the group using the rotate API.

Comment: No. That's not what I meant for. It doesn't rotate good, it doesn't rotate around the center.